# JWT decode error: 'Could not deserialize key data' using jwt in Python but the token works when I paste it into online decoders

Tags: python, jwt

The full error is this:

'Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [_OpenSSLErrorWithText(code=75497580, lib=9, reason=108, reason_text=b'error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line')]'.

When I paste the token into https://jwt.io/ (it also says RS256 is the algo) it works fine but when I run this code:

```
import jwt
jwt.decode('eyJ0..............', algorithms=['RS256'])
```

I get the above error. What am I doing wrong? The token is generated through the MSAL package using the acquireSilentToken method in the MSAL-browser npm package.

Comment: As far as I know `RS256` requires a key to encode and decode... Are you sure the algorithm is correct? can you share the token (or a similar one with mock data)?

Comment: @MatteoZanoni Thanks for the quick response! I will look into generating one with mock data. Maybe a stupid question but if it required a key, why would it work on jwt.io and other pages aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging further I was able to replicate your problem by using a mock JWT generated on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io).

Looking at the traceback the problem seemed to be related to the key format (not the jwt format).

The `key` parameter to `jwt.decode` is optional and the default value is an empty string. This is because it is only used if the option `verify_signature` is true.
Unfortunatelly the default value of such option is `True` so your code was trying to verify the signature of the JWT using an invalid public key (an empty string).

If you do not need to verify the signature than just set the options accordingly:

```py
import jwt

jwt.decode(
    'eyJ0..............',
    algorithms=['RS256'],
    options={"verify_signature": False},
)
```